# Error: The specified structure must be blittable or have layout information. (Parameter 'structure') when I want to convert byte [] to object

Tags: c#, marshalling

I'm trying to convert from byte[] to object using such a simple method.

My code:

```
private object ByteArrayToObject(byte[] bArray)
{
    var size = Marshal.SizeOf(bArray.Length);
    var bytes = new byte[size];
    var ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
    Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, ptr, size);
    var returnObject = (object)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(object));
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);

    return returnObject;
}

byte[] requestDataByte = data.Data;
object requestDataObject = ByteArrayToObject(requestDataByte);
```

When I run the code I get the following error:
The specified structure must be blittable or have layout information.

What am I doing wrong and how do I do it right? :)

Comment: `object` isn't a structure

Comment: Please help to convert from byte[] to object.

Comment: @ВолодимирLivePege that simply doesn't make sense, by which I mean: it isn't defined. This API is talking about unwrapping a struct from raw memory (following some P/Invoke rules, not a direct copy). That isn't a thing you can do for "object" - what type would it even use? It sounds like you're either looking for a serialization API, or a struct blit. But the thing you're actually asking for literally doesn't make sense. So: in order for us to help you, what is it that you are trying to *do*? What is the payload here, where did it come from, and what object are you expecting to create?

Comment: Also, perhaps a minor point in the grand scheme, but you seem to be allocating unmanaged memory, copying the payload to there, reading from the copy, then releasing the unmanaged memory. To be clear: none of that is necessary. Even if you use Marshal (which I don't think will be what you want); you can read from there directly (via `fixed`)

Comment: To add to @MarcGravell 's comments. A **byte[]** is already an object. object in C# is the base for all types. You can easily use 'object requestDataObject = requestDataByte;'. I really don't know why you would do that though.